# increment number table - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just a simple question for a beginner in TSQL.

I just want to know how do I write a set base INSERT query for a number table where it just contain a list of numbers. The numbers may vary but for example if I want 5 numbers, the number table should output 20 rows with each row containing an increment number like so:

```
NumberID
1
2
3
4
5
```

Then lets say I decide to change the number to 7, it will display below:

```
NumberID
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

How do I do that?

Comment: `"if I want 5 numbers, the number table should output 20 rows" ?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a recursive query using a [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx). Maximum possible number is 32767.

```
DECLARE @Number INT = 5

;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT num = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT num + 1 FROM x WHERE num < @Number
)
SELECT num FROM x
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use row_number() function

```
select number from 
(
Select row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as number from sys.objects
) as t where number<=5
```

or

```
Select top 5 row_number() over (order by (select 0)) as number from sys.objects
```